# Remaining characters if data exists Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a web site where users create an account and that information is saved to a JSON. When the user hits "save" the page refreshes and that data is echoed in the field pulling from the JSON. The problem I am experiencing is in one text area I want to limit the amount of characters. The script works perfectly IF there is no data in that textarea. The problem, that I can't figure out, is if there is data, because the user saved it, the countdown text is still 100 and the user can continue typing more information. What I want is when the page refreshes, the Javascript counts the JSON information pre-filled in that text area and counts. Basically once the user saves the data into the JSON and the page refreshes the Javascript counts whatever text is pre-populated. Hope this makes sense. Here are the codes I have.

The text area

```
<textarea spellcheck="false" id="textarea" maxlength="100" 
name="welcome" required><?php if (!empty($main_data->welcome)) 
{ echo urldecode($main_data->welcome); } ?></textarea>
```

The Javascript:

```
<script>   
$(document).ready(function() {
var text_max = 100;
$('#textarea_feedback').html(text_max + ' characters remaining');

$('#textarea').keyup(function() {
    var text_length = $('#textarea').val().length;
    var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;

    $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_remaining + ' characters remaining');
});
});

</script>
```

Comment: try `$("#textarea").trigger("keyup")` at the end of you script..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) the event after binding it on page load. The method will execute the event handler and thus the desired result will be achieved.

> Execute all handlers and behaviors attached to the matched elements for the given event type.

```
$('#textarea').on(......).trigger('keyup'); //Notice here
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var text_max = 100;
  $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_max + ' characters remaining');

  $('#textarea').on('keyup', function() {
    var text_length = $('#textarea').val().length;
    var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;

    $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_remaining + ' characters remaining');
  }).trigger('keyup'); //Notice here
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea spellcheck="false" id="textarea" maxlength="100" name="welcome" required>PrefilledText</textarea>
<div id="textarea_feedback"></div>
```

However, I would recommend you to create a method. Then you can invoke it on page load and use it as event handler.

```
function setFeedback() {
    var text_length = $('#textarea').val().length;
    var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;

    $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_remaining + ' characters remaining');
}

//Set on page load
setFeedback();

//Bind event
$('#textarea').on('keyup', setFeedback);
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace your code to the following:

```
<script>   
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#textarea').keyup(showRemainingCharacters).trigger("keyup");
});
function showRemainingCharacters() {
    var maxLength = 100,
        currentLength = $('#textarea').val().length,
        remainingLength = maxLength - currentLength;

    $('#textarea_feedback').html(remainingLength + ' characters remaining');    
}

</script>
```

Comment: nice solution with the function.. better for reuse.. and also binding could be a little more simple `$('#textarea').keyup(showRemainingCharacters).trigger("keyup")`

Comment: I personally follow your previous approach.

Comment: Well actually me too, because you could extend the function with parameters to reuse them for other elements. But on the other side, I prefer clean and short code, so I updated it anyways.. Thanks.

Comment: in case you need to send any parameters just append then after the event type.. `.trigger("keyup", { userId: 1 });`. You can pass objects or array.